# Issue with "Browse" Button Visibility in Shiny Dashboard with Bootswatch Cerulean Theme

Tags: r, shiny

I am facing an issue with the visibility of the "Browse" button in the `fileInput` widget within a Shiny Dashboard application using the Bootswatch Cerulean theme. The "Browse" button does not display as expected, making it difficult for users to understand how to upload a file.

Here's a simplified example of my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        tags$head(
            tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "https://bootswatch.com/5/cerulean/bootstrap.css")
        ),
        fileInput("file1", "Upload a file")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see, the "Browse" button is not clearly visible with the Cerulean theme. I would like to make it visible and easily clickable for users. Is there a way to adjust the CSS or settings to resolve this visibility issue when using the Cerulean theme?

Any guidance or solutions on improving the user experience in this context would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a handy inspect element, I can see for some reason this theme has set the width of the file input button (CSS class .input-group-btn) to 1% instead of something reasonable like 10%. This is why the button is 'hidden'. See screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

You can customise the CSS associated with this particular button by using its tag and adding in CSS which specifies its width: 10%. You could also add in a border and change the colour of the button if you wish. More about using custom CSS in Shiny apps [here.](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/css/)

I've added some in-file custom CSS for this button below, but be aware that this CSS will affect every future element with the tag '.input-group-btn', i.e. if you include another fileInput widget, in another part of the app, it will have its button set to a width of 10% too. In the future, it would be good practice to set up a separate CSS file which contains your CSS code to style your app, including the CSS for styling the button.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "https://bootswatch.com/5/cerulean/bootstrap.css"),
      tags$style(HTML("
                      
                      .input-group-btn {
                        width: 10%;
                      }

                      "))
    ),
    wellPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Upload a file")
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```